# AngularJS not parsing data correctly in foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason I amfiltering and my data is returning multiply times.
for example if I have and ID return of 456, the data will return to row 4,5 and 6.
Its driving me crazy. why is it looking at

[Plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jIDGJ96pBtpcASnD757n?p=preview)

```js
var question = $filter('filter')($scope.existingList, {
  QuestionID: item.QuestionID
});
console.log(question);
if(!item.answer && question.length>0 || !item.answer === item.answer){
  //console.log(question);
  item.answer = question[0].Response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `if` condition to this `if(!item.answer && question.length>0){`

http://plnkr.co/edit/GEHRP4g1RyvwOPq9ntZq?p=preview